# Why apt-get install nginx-extras not working?

Tags: python, nginx, ssh

[image]

As above image, I tried to install nginx-extras on Ubuntu 10.04 x64 with

```
apt-get install nginx-extras
```

When the setup ask permission, I pressed Y and clicked enter but it shows abort. is it ok? I am newbie in Linux, My setup is brand new and only installed python and PPA source.

Comment: I don't know what happened then... But it is working now. Problem solved

Comment: Sometimes it does matter if you're typing 'Y' or 'y', or even sometimes to need to write 'Yes' / 'yes'.

Comment: In that time, I tried y and Y both.. (I tried 2 times wit cap y and sm y)

Answer (score 0):

Just type `sudo apt-get install nginx-extras`, enter your password when asked
and pressed `Y` when asked for permission.